# Azure Data Factory - How to transform object with dynamic keys to array in a data flow?

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-data-factory

After spending many hours of reading the documentation, following some tutorials and trial & error, i just can't figure it out; how can I transform the following complex object with key objects to an array using a data flow in Azure Data Factory?

**Input**

```json
{
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": 1234
  },
  "body": {
    "00b50a39-8591-3db3-88f7-635e2ec5c65a": {
      "id": "00b50a39-8591-3db3-88f7-635e2ec5c65a",
      "name": "Example 1",
      "date": "2023-02-09"
    },
    "0c206312-2348-391b-99f0-261323a94d95": {
      "id": "0c206312-2348-391b-99f0-261323a94d95",
      "name": "Example 2",
      "date": "2023-02-09"
    },
    "0c82d1e4-a897-32f2-88db-6830a21b0a43": {
      "id": "00b50a39-8591-3db3-88f7-635e2ec5c65a",
      "name": "Example 3",
      "date": "2023-02-09"
    },
  }
}
```

**Expected output**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "00b50a39-8591-3db3-88f7-635e2ec5c65a",
    "name": "Example 1",
    "date": "2023-02-09"
  },
  {
    "id": "0c206312-2348-391b-99f0-261323a94d95",
    "name": "Example 2",
    "date": "2023-02-09"
  },
  {
    "id": "00b50a39-8591-3db3-88f7-635e2ec5c65a",
    "name": "Example 3",
    "date": "2023-02-09"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AFAIK**, Your JSON keys are dynamic. So, getting the desired result using dataflow might not be possible.

In this case, you can try the below approach as a workaround. This will work only if all of your key's length is same.

**This is my Pipeline:**

[image]

- First I have used a **lookup activity** to get the JSON file and converted the lookup output to a string and stored in a variable using below expression.
  `@substring(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body),2,sub(length(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body)),4))`.
- Then I have used **split on that String variable** with `'},"'` and stored in an array variable using below expression.
  `@split(variables('res_str'),'},"')`
  It will give the array like below.

  [image]
- Give that array to a **ForEach** and inside ForEach use an **append variable** activity to store the keys into an array with below expression.
  `@take(item(), 36)`
- Now, I got the list of keys in an array, after the above ForEach use another ForEach activity to get the desired array of objects. Use append variable actvity inside ForEach and give the below expression for it.
  `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body[item()]`

**Result array after ForEach will be:**

[image]

If you want to store the above JSON into a file, you need to use `OPENJSON` from SQL. This is because copy activity additonal column only supports string type not an array type.

Use a SQL dataset on copy activity source and give the below SQL script in the query.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  N'@{variables('json_arr')}'  
   
SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              id varchar(200) '$.id' ,  
              name varchar(32)     '$.name',  
              date varchar(32) '$.date'
 )
```

In Sink, give a JSON dataset and select Array of Objects as File pattern.

[image]

Execute the pipeline and you will get the above array inside a file.

**This is my Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
"name": "pipeline1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Lookup1",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "JsonSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "Json1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Lookup output to Str",
            "description": "",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "res_str",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@substring(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body),2,sub(length(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body)),4))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Split Str to array",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup output to Str",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "split_arr",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@split(variables('res_str'),'},\"')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "build keys array using split array",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Split Str to array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('split_arr')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "take first 36 chars of every item",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "keys_array",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@take(item(), 36)",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "build final array using keys array",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "build keys array using split array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('keys_array')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "description": "append every object to array",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "json_arr",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].body[item()]",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Just for Res show",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "build final array using keys array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "final_res_show",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@variables('json_arr')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Copy data1",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Just for Res show",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)\nSET @json =   \n  N'@{variables('json_arr')}'  \n   \nSELECT * FROM  \n OPENJSON ( @json )  \nWITH (   \n              id varchar(200) '$.id' ,  \n              name varchar(32)     '$.name',  \n              date varchar(32) '$.date'\n )",
                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                    "partitionOption": "None"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "JsonSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                        "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Target_JSON",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "res_str": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "split_arr": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "keys_array": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "final_res_show": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "json_arr": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

**Result file:**

[image]